# Updating list references

Tags: c#, linq

In the example below, why does the count differ? Isn't bar a reference to foo?

```
IEnumerable<string> foo = new List<string> { "a", "b" };
var bar = foo;
foo = foo.Skip(1);

// foo.Count() = 1
// bar.Count() = 2
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET.

Comment: `Enumerable.Skip` method bypasses a specified number of elements in a sequence and then returns the remaining elements. It is often used for pagination through LINQ when querying relational databases.

Comment: I think confusing came from the type. if `foo` was a list adding to `bar` will add to foo too. But to use `Skip`, you change the type to `IEnumerable`.  Skip , yield return the result to you ([source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L638)). It doesnt work on the undelying object. perhaps you where looking for a `.RemoveAt(0);`

Comment: @DragandDrop: No, the change in type doesn't matter at all. It's the fact that it's assigning a new value to `foo` that's important here. The last line could be `foo = new List<string> { "x" };` - no changes of type, but still the same results.

Comment: @Jon, I believe we are looking in the same direction. My point was Skip return something it's an assignation. Not a work on the orginal reference object in place. If Op add kept List he would have use Skip(1).ToList() and the result would have been obvious.

Comment: @DragandDrop: And that's fine, but look at your comment: "I think confusing came from the type" and "But to use Skip, you change the type to IEnumerable". *It's got nothing to do with the type*. (Imagine if the example were changed to `foo = foo.FindAll(x => x == "a");` - it's the exact same scenario, but every aspect of "changing type" goes away.)

Comment: @HansPassant: No it's not. It's a reference to an `IEnumerable` implementation - it's *not* `List<T>.Enumerator`, which implements `IEnumerator<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. If `Skip` returned a `List<T>.Enumerator`, it couldn't be assigned to `foo` which is of type `IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Isn't bar a reference to foo?

No, the *initial value of `bar`* is a copy of the value of `foo` at the time of initialization. Note that the value of `foo` is not an object - it's a *reference*.

Changing the value of `foo` to refer to something different (as you do in the following line) doesn't change the value of `bar` at all.

Simpler example:

```cs
string x = "original";
string y = x;
x = "different";
Console.WriteLine(y); // Still prints "original"
```

Comment: Hmm, you're saying it's a copy but `Object.ReferenceEquals(foo, bar)` is true before skip is applied?

Comment: @filur: The value of `foo` is a reference - it's a copy of that value. It's not a reference to a clone of the object. (So yes, `Object.ReferenceEquals(foo, bar)` would indeed be true until you change the value of `foo`. It would still be true if you wrote `foo.Add("x")` because that doesn't change the value of `foo` - it's still a reference to the same list object.

Comment: So what does skip do in this case to loose the reference?

Comment: @filur: What do you mean by "loose the reference"? `Skip` just returns a reference to a different object (and you're then assigning that reference to `foo`). It doesn't "lose" anything.

Comment: Sorry for bad wording. What I mean is that the reference to the same object is "lost", e.g. `Object.ReferenceEquals(foo, bar)` is false after the skip code. I'm out on deep water here but is it because new iterator instance being created?

Comment: @filur: No, calling Skip does *not* create a new iterator at all. But `Skip` returns a different reference to the one that it's called on - that's *all* you need to know (in terms of why ReferenceEquals returns false). It's not LINQ-specific, it's not iterator-specific - Skip is just "a method that returns a reference other than `this`".